# assertion/comparison of 2 unmatched string objects is logged as error instead of failure

Tags: ant, junit, junit4

I executed a simple test case (on jobss-ejb environment), which compares/asserts 2 strings. 
Unfortunately, the strings are not matching to each other (there's a bug). 

But the problem is, when I execute the test case from **eclipse** it logs the result as **failure** which is correct because there's a mismatch between expected and actual objects; 

whereas when I execute the same test case from **ant**, the result is logged as **error**.

This is really strange and surprising and to add more to it, this behaviour is noticed on **junit 4 version only**, when i execute the test case on junit 3.8, both ant and eclipse log the result as failure.

Any suggestion or pointers on what might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Ant-version: 1.6.1
Junit version: 4.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences in test result behavior as mentioned in question is because of **ant version issue**. For lower versions of ant, you'll get such type of behavior (may be because the lower ant versions consider **ComparisonFailure** as error instead of failure).
I found this behavior in **ant version 1.7.1** (and lower). But this **issue is solved** in latest **ant jar** i.e. **1.8.4**.
When I executed the above mentioned test case on latest ant version, the **result** was logged as **failure** and **not error**.
So, if you encounter such a problem **just update your ant jar to 1.8.4** or other latest version available.

Comment: Did not work for me. I am using junit 4.11 and ant 1.8.4. I tried with assertEquals("a", "b");

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i digged down further and found that this is not related to any specific application server. It can be reproduced on **any app server**.
Just create a sample (junit4) test case as mentioned below:

```
@Test
public void stringTest() {
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("Comparing 2 string:", "abc", "xyz");
}
```

Now, run it from eclipse; you will see  result as 1 failure.
Run the same via some app server, using an **ant (or maven) target** and you will get the result as error.

After going through the logs I think that this must be because the junit4 org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(String message, Object expected,Object actual) method throws **ComparisonFailure** instead of **AssertionError**. 
My analysis on this is that junit4 assert() method (org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(String, Object, Object)) throws ComparisonFailure only for String instances.
Following is the code of org.junit.Assert.assertEquals (**junit4** assert method):

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null)
        return;
    if (expected != null && isEquals(expected, actual))
        return;
    else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage= message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
}
```

And this is the code for junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(String, Object, Object) (i.e. **junit3** assert method)

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null && actual == null)
        return;
    if (expected != null && expected.equals(actual))
        return;
    failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
}
```

It can be observed that in **junit4 assertEquals()** an extra check is added for unequal String instances which throws **ComparisonFailure** for two unequal strings. For all other unequal objects i.e Integer, Long,etc. the call goes to **failNotEquals()** method which throws an **AssertionError**.

Can anyone help me to understand the **design significance** of adding a String instance check in junit4's org.junit.Assert.assertEquals() method. Why is it really added and why only for String?